# Is it possible to hide the text in JTextArea by clicking on some its area?

Tags: java, swing, text-editor

I'm currently implementing a simple text editor for personal purposes, something like quick notes. I will use it as my task planer. For this I need some specifical tags to be implemented. For example, lets say, I have 2 tasks for today and they look like this:

```
{Uni, 29.12.2015} do some homework {Uni, 29.12.2015} °

{Home, 29.12.2015} do some stuff here {Home, 29.12.2015} °
```

What I need now is, when clicking on the circle, the tags will dissapear and it will look like this:

```
do some homework °

do some stuff here °
```

By clicking on the circle again, the tags would appear again.

My question is, is it actually possible to implement this using java? I know how to show/hide text, but I don't know how to implement this "circle button functionality". I'm currently using swing library for main functionalities of my editor, but I'm not sure if I can make it work using this library. Is there some library that allows this? Unfortunately, google didn't bring me further. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need now is, when clicking on the circle,

Swing text components support a `viewToModel(...)` method.

So you could add a MouseListener to the text area and get the character represented where the mouse was clicked. It the character is your special circle then you toggle the text.